# Making progress bar in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, progress

I wish to do something like a progress bar animation in Android app.

I'm trying to make a simple line which Width increases.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.init_line);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(i, 2);
    iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
    try { Thread.sleep(20); }
    catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

However is not working and it doesn't appear nothing on the screen. It would be great if you guys could give me a hand on this. Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot see you `ImageView` because you haven't added it to your content view.

Answer (score 1):

Android has a Predefined class for a progress bar, its in a class called ProgressDialog. It looks like this:

[image]

You can add this codes in your onCreate() and set the state of the progressDialog like this:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Downloading Music :) ");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
```

For more details you can check the Android API Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

This [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_progressbar.htm) has a full application demo about it, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your code in onResume or a method that is called when the Activity (or Fragment) is visible to the user. onCreate is called when the Activity is first created and is where you should do your *static* setup.